# Retrieve data from Header template of Datalist

Tags: asp.net, datalistitem

I have one `checkbox` control in `Datalist` Header and some controls in Item Template. On click of the "**Submit**" button in the page I should capture the state of controls from Datalist.

For `Item template` I can get the values from `datalist.Items` property.

How can I get the state of checkbox in "Header Template"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) DataListID.Controls
    .OfType<DataListItem> ()
    .First (a => a.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    .FindControl("<CheckBoxID>");
```